# $L \otimes \bar{K}$ is never a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

> Let $K$ be a field and $L$ be a simple extension $(i.e.\  L=K(\alpha))$. Let $\bar K$ denotes the algebraic closure of $K$. Then prove that  $L \otimes \bar{K}$ is never a field.

If $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ then  $$K[x]/(f(x))\cong K(\alpha) \implies K[x]/(f)\otimes_{K} \bar{K}  \cong K(\alpha)\otimes_K \bar{K}. $$
If, I can show that $$ K[x]/(f)\otimes_{K} \bar{K} \cong\bar{K}[x]/(f) ,$$ then I can prove the result. So help me in proving the above claim.

Comment: Maybe you can prove by contradiction that if the tensor product were a field, then it would be a finite (whence algebraic) extension of the algebraic closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe the map $$ \phi : \bar{K}[x]\to  K[x]/(f)\otimes_{K} \bar{K} $$ $$ \sum_{i=0}^na_i x^i\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^n\bar{x}^i\otimes a_i $$

1. Show that $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism.
2. Ker$(\phi)=(f)$

Conclude your claim.